# How to run Eclipse plugin in the same Workbench?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created simple Eclipse plugin, by wizard, `Hello, World Command`, but it runs in separate Eclipse.

Is it possible to run plugin in the same Eclipse I work in?

I want to write some helpers for design process.

**UPDATE**

My Eclipse version is Juno

My OS version is Windows Prof 7 x64

Eclipse runs under `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/bin/javaw.exe` according to `eclipse.ini`

Run configuration of `Eclipse Application` refers the same location.

Comment: The [vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) explain this, and the example does load in same eclipse.

Comment: It runs in different Eclipse for me

Comment: Even it is said in your link: "A new Eclipse workbench starts."

Comment: Look at chapter 8. No, you can't do it without installing the plugin in some way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to **install your plugin in your Eclipse** to run it with-in the Eclipse as other plugins.

FAQ on Eclipse Plugin Installation can be found here: [**FAQ How do I install new plug-ins?**](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_install_new_plug-ins%3F)

Comment: Is it possible RUN plugin under Eclipse without installation?